# How to get rid of app name in the particular url?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this urls.py in my app

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from products import views


app_name = 'products'
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'products', views.ProductViewSet, basename='products')
router.register(r'categories', views.ProductCategoryViewSet, basename='categories')
router.register(r'brands', views.BrandViewSet, basename='brands')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

And this is my project's urls.py

```
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/login.html'),
         name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='users/logout.html'),
         name='logout'),
    path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += [
    ...
    path('products/', include('products.urls', namespace='products')),
    ...
]
```

And viewsets:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .models import (
    Product,
    ProductCategory,
    Brand,
)
from .serializers import ProductSerializer, ProductCategorySerializer, BrandSerializer

#all other viewsets are the same
class ProductViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
```

A router for my app generates urls almost as expected, I can go to 'site/products/categories' for categories 'site/products/brands' for brands BUT for products url is 'site/products/products'. How to make it not to add app name in this case? I want it to be just 'site/products'.

Comment: router.register(r'', views.ProductViewSet, basename='products') should work

Comment: @TrueGopnik Thanks, it made 'site/products' a valid url BUT ruined urls for brands and categories.

Comment: Put it under line where you are registering brands router

Comment: @TrueGopnik Thank you! It's working now. But why did it work? Why didn't it work for the first time? Anyway, can you add an answer to the question so I can accept it?

Comment: Sure, added answer and my understanding of this behaviour

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from django.urls import path, include
from rest_framework.routers import DefaultRouter
from products import views


app_name = 'products'
router = DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'categories', views.ProductCategoryViewSet, basename='categories')
router.register(r'brands', views.BrandViewSet, basename='brands')
router.register(r'', views.ProductViewSet, basename='products')

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

Django is trying to match url to one url from list of router urls, so if you have two same urls, but one is faster in list, Django will pick always the first one.